# Make text fields' positions match buttons' positions + keep controls where they are

Tags: css, html

**New question:**

On my page http://goo.gl/ t3Ofk (remove the space in your browser, please don't replace the link here as I don't want google to link this page to my site.) when you resize your browser to something smaller than about 300 pixels width, the controls below Ortseingabe change position in an undesired way. How do I keep *Übersicht* to the left, the slider in the middle and *Detail* on the right(the button may move) regardless of browser size?

```
**Old question:**

On my page http://goo.gl/ t3Ofk (remove the space in your browser, please don't replace the link here as I don't want google to link this page to my site.) when you resize your browser the grey text fields don't match the buttons' positions.

Two questions:

 1. What do I need to change for the text fields' right borders to stay apart 2 pixels from the buttons' right borders?
 2. When you resize your browser to something smaller than about 300 pixels width, the controls below Ortseingabe change position in an undesired way. How do I keep *Übersicht* to the left, the slider in the middle and *Detail* on the right(the button may move) regardless of browser size?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give your input field a width of 100% not 97%. Then wrap that input field and button in a div, give that div a left and right padding of 10px.

```
<div class="block search-bl">           
<h3><i class="pull-right" id="suchen"></i>Was suchen Sie?</h3>
<div style="padding: 0 10px;">            
    <input type="search" name="suchbegriff" id="name">
    <button class="search-button" value="Suche beginnen" name="suche" type="submit" onclick="changeAction('eingabe.php?lat=50.94567147679&amp;lon=6.97363018295688&amp;ortsangabe=Position nicht ermittelbar&amp;radius=14&amp;breite=800')">Suchen                                                                                     
    </button>  
</div>        
<p class="info-help">Hinweis: Drücken Sie die Eingabetaste statt auf Suchen zu klicken.              
</p>
```

Comment: Perfect. I changed it to <div style="padding-top:0px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-right:20px;padding-left:0px;"> though.